# Question about some type of element in C struct

Tags: c, struct

I have some issue understanding some code in C.
Here is an extract :

```
typedef struct player_s {
  point_t (*get_action)(struct player_s *, game_state_t *);
  void (*setup_boats)(struct player_s *, game_state_t *);
  char *name;
  point_t owned_rect[2];
  int n_boats;
} player_t;
```

I don't understand what do the 2 first line of this struct..
They also do this :

```
local_player_t *ret = calloc(1, sizeof(*ret));
ret->base.get_action = playerLocalAction;
```

local_player_t is a struct that contain a player_t.

and here is playerLocalAction prototype :

```
static point_t playerLocalAction(player_t *self, game_state_t *game);
```

I really don't understand what's appening in this code..
If you can help me thanks !

(Sorry for my bad english, I have to work on it x) )

Comment: They're function pointers

Comment: Oh, okay, I thought that fonction pointers needed to be assigned to a void* but seems like I was wrong !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are pointers to a function. They are defined as :

```
 [ret_type] (*[ptr_name])([arg_types])
```

Those function pointers are very useful in many situations, allowing a better modularity.